# Avoid Re-Rendering Child Components in React

Tags: reactjs

In my react app, I'm rendering a list of items in the render method, each with its unique and deterministic key. However, whenever render is called, each item's constructor gets called again, removing the old item from the DOM and adding a new one. Why is this happening? How do I make it so that each child component doesn't re-render?

```
<Rect key={`${i}-${j}-rect`} ...
```

I thought that providing a unique key for each item would prevent this, but each item in the list is still re-rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, turns out I wasn't assigning keys correctly. I changed my key to a unique identifier (in this case, the date of each data point) and now children aren't disposed of each time render is called. Make sure to try to avoid array indexes when assigning keys to components.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I was going to tell you. Probably was that. If they have same key the items in the list should only be re rendered